# Spark application log messages not showing in EMR logs

Tags: scala, logging, apache-spark, emr

I'm running a spark job on EMR, but my log messages aren't being written to the logs. I'd expect my log messages to be intermingled with the spark log messages as happens when I run a hadoop job. When I run my job locally, my log messages are printed as expected in the rest of the log output.

I've tried the following which don't work:

`import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
...
val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyPoc.getClass())
logger.info("message here")`

and

`import org.apache.log4j.Logger
...
val logger = Logger.getRootLogger()
logger.info("message here")`

and

`import org.apache.spark.Logging
object MyPoc extends App with Logging {
  ...
  logInfo("message here")
  ...
}`

How can I write log messages to the log files from a spark job running on EMR?

I'm launching my job as follows:

`aws  emr create-cluster --name EMR-Spark-PoC --ami-version 3.3.1 \
--instance-type=m1.medium --instance-count 2 \
--ec2-attributes KeyName=key-dev,InstanceProfile=EMRJobflowDefault \
--log-uri s3://my-logs/emr/ \
--bootstrap-action Name=Spark,Path=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/install-spark,Args=[-x] \
--steps Name=SparkPoC,Jar=s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,Args=[/home/hadoop/spark/bin/spark-submit,--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn-cluster,--class,my.poc.EmrPoc,s3://my-dev/poc-0.0.1.jar,s3n://my-data/avro/part-m-00000.avro,s3n://my-data/avro/part-m-00000.avro] \
--no-auto-terminate`

I've built a fat jar using assembly. Here's most of my build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.2.0",
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "0.1"
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case x if x.endsWith(".class") => MergeStrategy.last
  case x if x.endsWith(".properties") => MergeStrategy.last
  case x if x.contains("/resources/") => MergeStrategy.last
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF/mailcap") => MergeStrategy.last
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF/mimetypes.default") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF/maven/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/pom.") => MergeStrategy.first
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    if (oldStrategy == MergeStrategy.deduplicate)
      MergeStrategy.first
    else
      oldStrategy(x)
}

assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := {
  val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
  cp filter {_.data.getName == "avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar"}
}
```

Comment: Are you running on YARN? How are you launching the cluster and submitting your job?

Comment: I'm using the instructions under "Example of an all-in-one AWS CLI command that creates the cluster, runs a Spark application, then terminates" on this page https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=126682&tstart=0

Comment: Do you think my merge strategy for the slf4j-api/pom might be at fault?

Comment: I don't think the logging should be set up by your application, it should be handled by the EMR bootstrap. It should save logs wherever YARN pushes logs

Comment: Yeah. When I log locally it all works fine. I think there's some dodgy log4j config on EMR.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bootstrap action on EMR to append your application log4j settings to the EMR log4j environment.

1) Sample bootstrap action

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
CUSTOM_LOG4J_FILE=$1
CUSTOM_LOG4J_FILE_NAME="customlog4j.txt"
echo "Starting to copy over logging configuration on EMR"
hadoop fs -get $CUSTOM_LOG4J_FILE /home/hadoop/
cat /home/hadoop/$CUSTOM_LOG4J_FILE_NAME >> /home/hadoop/conf/log4j.properties
exit 0
```

2) Sample Contents of customlog4j.txt

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=ERROR
log4j.logger.akka=ERROR
log4j.logger.io=ERROR
log4j.my.poc=DEBUG
```

Note : if you only need to change log4j options for the Spark driver , the `install-spark` bootstrap action has an `-l` option